# How can I handle an option made of an arbitrary number with Getopt::Long[::Descriptive]?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I would like to be able to handle options like `-1` or `-10` similarly to how `head` or `-tail` do.

In other words, be able to do

```
my_script.pl -10 --some-other-option arguments
```

and be able to retain the value of the `-10` option.

Right now the only idea that works is processing the command line *before* it is fed to describe_options like so:

```perl
my ($count) = map { /\-(\d+)/; $1 } grep { /^\-(\d+)$/ } reverse @ARGV;
@ARGV = grep { !/^\-\d+$/ } @ARGV;

my ($opt, $usage) = describe_options(...)
```

but it looks clunky, and the option doesn't pop up in `$usage`.

Is there a better way? Answers using Getopt::Long will work too - I can adapt them to GetOpt::Long::Descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Getopt::Long` (Not sure about `Getopt::Long::Descriptive`) can be configured to call a user-supplied function on unknown arguments; this can be used to handle such cases.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
# :config required to enable handling of "<>" psuedo-option
use Getopt::Long qw/:config pass_through/;
use Scalar::Util qw/looks_like_number/;

my $verbose = 0;
my $lines = 10;
GetOptions("verbose" => \$verbose,
           "<>" => \&parse_lines)
    or die "Unable to parse options.\n";
say "Lines is $lines";

sub parse_lines {
    my $arg = shift;
    if (looks_like_number $arg) {        
        $lines = $arg =~ s/^-//r; # Turn -X into X
    } else {
        die "Invalid option '$arg'\n";
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
$ perl foo.pl -123
Lines is 123
$ perl foo.pl --bar
Invalid option '--bar'
Unable to parse options.
```

Comment: it seems that _this_ is one case where Getopt::Long and  Getopt::Long::Descriptive differ, my bad for thinking it'd be the case